# how to handle if the code is getting stuck at reading MFRC522 module, doesn't retrive if gets stuck. I'm using MFRC522 UART library python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, uart, rfid, mfrc522

I'm using this MFRC522 UART library in python [This](https://github.com/mfdogalindo/MFRC522-UART)
While reading if the module gets reset it stops reading doesn't print anything.
This is read.py which is calling the external class MFRC522.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-


import MFRC522
import signal
import threading

continue_reading = True
SECTORS_TOREAD = 8
sector_now = 0

# Capture SIGINT for cleanup when the script is aborted
def end_read(signal,frame):
    global continue_reading
    print "Ctrl+C captured, ending read."
    continue_reading = False
    exit()

# Hook the SIGINT
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, end_read)

# Create an object of the class MFRC522
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()

# Welcome message
print "Welcome to the MFRC522 data read example"
print "Press Ctrl-C to stop."

def rfid_check():
    # This loop keeps checking for chips. If one is near it will get the UID and authenticate
    while continue_reading:
        try:
            # Scan for cards    
            (status,TagType) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Request(MIFAREReader.PICC_REQA)

        
            # Get the UID of the card
            (status,uid) = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Anticoll()

            # If we have the UID, continue
            if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
                # Print UID
                print "Card read UID: "+str(uid[0])+","+str(uid[1])+","+str(uid[2])+","+str(uid[3])
        except:
            print("HANDLING EXCEPTION")

threading.Thread(target=rfid_check).start
```

and I don't know how to handle if my rfid_check function if it gets stuck while calling the external MFRC522 class
Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have tried timeout but it didn't work for me

Comment: you got any logs?

Comment: Gets stuck where?  In the `MFRC522_Request` call?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes it gets stuck in MFRC522_Request call if I reset the module and it gets stuck at object creation of MFRC522 class too

Comment: @drum actually I'm using command line interface in linux to run the program so when it stuck it is not really printing anything